# QR Factorization for Solving Least Squares

Tags: matrices, least-squares

By solving Least Squares, we use 
$RX = Q^Tb$

What's the benefit for solving least squares using QR factorization instead of solving the normal equations? and Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope it can help you

QR factorization method is more stable because it avoids forming $A^TA$

**Example:**
 a ${3 \times 2}$ matrix with 'almost linearly dependent' columns

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 10^{-5}  \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
, $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,b = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
10^{-5}  \\
1  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

round intermediate results to 8 significant decimal digits

**Method 1:** from $A^TA$ and solve normal equations

$A^TA = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1+10^{-10}  \\
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,A^Tb = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
10^{-10}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

after rounding ,the $A^TA$ is singular ,hence method fails.

**Method 2:** QR factorization of A is

$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
, $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,R= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
0 & 10^{-5}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

rounding does not change any values

---

[Lest squares lecture](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/133A/lectures/ls.pdf)